# sonarqube 6.0 add a project to custom dashboard

Tags: sonarqube

I am running sonarqube 6.0 and I have multiple teams for me. would like create the dashboard specific to group of java projects so that I can see the dashboard per team instead of seeing all the projects in global dashboard.

Can someone help me create the dashboard for group of projects

Comment: sidenote: you are aware that dashboards are gone since version 6.2 - so every upgrade to the next LTS will result in no dashboards

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to have dashboards per team, I would recommend you to use the Portfolio organization feature provided by the (commercial) [Entreprise Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/enterprise/).

As a side note, you should first consider upgrade to the latest LTS, 6.7.3